# How to load a ctype library in multiple Python processes?

Tags: python, subprocess, ctypes, python-multiprocessing

I have a golang library which I need to call from Python. I build it to a `.so` library and load it in Python via `cdll.LoadLibrary()`, it works well.

Now I need to use the library in both my main process and in a subprocess established by `multiprocessing.Process()`. (I understand that if I use thread this won't be a problem but I need to use Process for some reason.) But the library cannot work well in the subprocess. It just halts from time to time. My guess is that the global variables in the lib are only initiated once (in the main process), so the subprocess cannot get access to those vars. I debugged this by printing some lines in the `init()` function in the golang lib, it indeed only prints once even if I called `cdll.LoadLibrary()` respectively in both processes.

I don't know how to fix this, i.e. how to load a whole new self-contained version of the library in the subprocess. (Alternatively if I can just load the library in the main process and let the subprocess access the lib that would work for me too, but that seems to be more complicated and I don't know how to do that either.)

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Simplified code sample:

```
from ctypes import cdll
from multiprocessing import Process
...

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./go_lib.so")
lib.do_some_thing() # <- works well
...

def worker():
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./go_lib.so")
    lib.do_some_thing() # <- won't work correctly

p = Process(target=worker)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: What if you pass the handle (*lib*) to the worker?

Comment: does the library work if you only do the `LoadLibrary` in the worker process (i.e. not in the main process)?  also if you start multiple processes?

Comment: @CristiFati I tried. It won't work.

Comment: @SamMason If I only load and call the lib in the worker, it works inside the subprocess. If I have 2 workers, they both work (given it's not loaded in the main process).

Comment: @SamMason Actually you made a good point here: It seems that I can put the job of my main process into another subprocess so the lib is only called in subprocesses. This might be a workaround. It's not an ideal solution though, as I have to make sure that the lib is never called anywhere in the main process (which is not easy for maintenance of a big codebase).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the issue you're facing is due to the library not coping with being in a program that `fork`s.  You have a few of obvious alternatives:

1. only use the library in child processes, like my experiment
2. only instantiate it in the parent process after forking off child processes. using a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) might make this easier, as processes are all forked when the pool is created and you can run code in them when needed.  you can load the library in the `initializer`
3. tell `multiprocessing` not to fork and [`spawn` processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) instead